# PHP - Not displaying anything from database -

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i have a problem displaying data from my database using LIMIT 2, it display nothing! no errors!
What i have now:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");
    if (!$con)
    {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("database", $con);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Stat LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);   ?>
    <html><head><title>.. </title></head><body>

    <?php 
        while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { ?> 
             <small><?php echo  $products['Followers'] ; ?> Followers </small>
        <?php } ?>
    </a>
```

So that display row 1 but if i change to this

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");
    if (!$con)
    {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("database", $con);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Stat LIMIT 2";
    $result = mysql_query($query);   ?>
    <html><head><title>.. </title></head><body>

    <?php 
        while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        ?>
```

It display nothing! Help! Can someone explain to me so i can learn.

main page (row 2) :

```
<div class="class">
<div class="class">
     <?php include '/includes/stat/connection2.php';?>
        <a href="<?php echo  $products['Site'] ; ?>" target="_blank"><img alt="<?php echo  $products['Title'] ; ?>" class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo  $products['Banner'] ; ?>
"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="class" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Total Votes">
        <?php include '/includes/stat/connection2.php';?>
<?php echo  $products['Votes'] ; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="class" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Followers">
        <?php include '/includes/stat/connection2.php';?>
<?php echo  $products['Followers'] ; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="reset"></div><hr>
    <h5>
        <a href="<?php echo  $products['Site'] ; ?>">
            <img alt="Profile" src="/images/home.gif">
        </a>
        <a href="<?php echo  $products['Site'] ; ?> " target="_blank">
        <?php include '/includes/stat/connection2.php';?>

<?php echo  $products['Title'] ; ?>
        </a>
    </h5>
<?php include '/includes/stat/connection2.php';?>
<?php echo  $products['Description'] ; ?>
</div>
```

Here is the main page. Connection2 is the query that has LIMIT 2

Comment: What is the Primary Key column name of 'Stat' table?

Comment: Try [`LIMIT 1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html#idm47124722880736) and don't use [deprecated `mysql_*` API](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) any more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add LIMIT to your query than it will return only one row. 
In limit you can limit the no. of returning rows in the query, and you can give range as 
well like this LIMIT 0,10 limit min,max

so change your query like this

```
$query = "SELECT Followers FROM Stat LIMIT 1";
```

also mysql are depriciated so use mysqli or PDO

For mysqli use check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

for PDO check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LIMIT clause in the SELECT query.

```
SELECT * FROM Stat LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Stat LIMIT 1";
```

LIMIT gives a limited amount of results to return.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT 1` to limit your query to the first row. The code below will return only the first raw in your table:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Stat LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query="select * from Stat limit 0,1";
```

Answer (score -1):

(Recommended for your case)You can optimize your query to select one row from the table -

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Stat LIMIT 1";
```

or you can use mysql_fetch_row() to get only one row from the whole result array

```
  while($products = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {?>`
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.